# How can i add 5 grace notes before a note, when only one grace note can fit in? (GuitarPRO)

Tags: guitar, notation, guitar-pro

Here's a part (measure 3) of "Tango En Skaï" (Roland Dyens) I am trying to write out.

[image: "Tango En Skaï", m. 3]

You can see there are 5 grace notes before the A, how would I add this in GuitarPRO?

[image: Transcription of m. 3 using GuitarPRO]

Here what it looks like when I try and add a grace note before.

Please help if you know how.

Update:

[image]

You can do it Sibelius!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Guitar Pro 7.5, it is not possible to add multiple grace notes in this way.

> **Grace-note before the beat:** A Grace note is an ornamentation that consists in a very short note played
> before an other one. In Guitar Pro, you can add a grace note for each string.
> However, *it is not possible to set several grace notes on the same string*. A grace note does not count for the bar duration and for the rhythm display.

(*[Guitar Pro 7.5 User Guide](https://static.guitar-pro.com/gp7/manual/GuitarPro7-user-guide.pdf)*, page 92).

Comment: is there any software I can use that would allow me to add several grace notes before a beat? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @jumpmanjo I know MuseScore can do it. Likely others (especially Sibelius and Finale), but you'd have to check.

Comment: Noteflight does support 5 grace notes on the same string.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsGf8.png